# Swift - Update an array of NSDictionary with values from another NSDictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parsing, nsdictionary

Basically, I have an `NSarray` of `dictionaries` coming as a JSON response only once when view appears. Now, I need to update a particular value of a key in those dictionaries with another set of dictionary coming separately in every few second such that I can update my array of dictionaries continuously with those values and show some realtime set of data on the screen.

**Example**: This is the array of dictionary I am getting from backend

```
[
  {item_id: 1001, name: "Apple", current_price: "$10"},
  {item_id: 1009, name: "Orange", current_price: "$15"},
  {item_id: 1004, name: "Mango", current_price: "$5"}
]
```

Current price is something which varies continuously, whose data I am receiving in `NSDictionary` format separately.

```
["1009": "$16", "1004": "$3", "1001": "$11"]
```

As you can see the new `NSDictionary` is mapped with the `item_id` to the current price value.

I need a way out to make sure the current price gets updated from this `NSDictionary` to the array of dictionary so that I can reuse that array to reload my `UITableview` and show the updated realtime price.

Comment: This is Swift. Why are you using `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`?

Comment: @the4kman i have just switched from objectiveC to Swift language, consider me being a beginner from that perspective. If you can edit the question to make it more Swift friendly then you are most welcome.

Comment: Could you clarify what is the technical difficulty you are having? Is it that you store prices in an array of dictionaries and have to go through the whole array each time prices are updated?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
let items = [["item_id": 1001, "name": "Apple", "current_price": "$10"], ["item_id": 1009, "name": "Orange", "current_price": "$15"], ["item_id": 1004, "name": "Mango", "current_price": "$5"]]

let prices = ["1009": "$16", "1004": "$3", "1001": "$11"]

let updatedItems = items.map { itemDict -> [String: Any] in
    var updatedItem = itemDict
    if let idKey = itemDict["item_id"] as? Int {
        prices["\(idKey)"].flatMap { updatedItem["current_price"] = $0 }
    }
    return updatedItem
}
```

Comment: If you need any explanations - feel free to ask :)